# PHP: download complete html code from url (with closed tags)

Tags: php, html, web, https

My problem is, that I want to download the html source code from url to a string or a file (that does not matter). I tried that with the "file_get_contents()" function, but when I try this, I am just getting parts of the code... There is a tag, which I can expand, but in code the tag is closed. How can I get this closed tag?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.